# Setting persistent environment variable in CentOS 7 issue

Tags: centos, environment-variables, reboot

I have been trying to set environment variables that would be saved upon reboot, but without success.

When I set variables using the `export` or `setenv` command, as root or any other user, it gets saved on the session until reboot. After reboot, the variables are lost.

In particular, I need to set `$JAVA_HOME`.

So I do like this

[image]

but nothing is working as I indicated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, paste the *actual text*...

Comment: I would argue that this is not a duplicate, the referenced question is not specifically for EL 7 type distros.

Comment: @jasonwryan @Anthon This is not a duplicate questions. User environment variables and system wide env vars like the OP is trying to set are different concepts. The linked question references `.bashrc` and methods that only work for a single user. This question  requires a system-wide method such as the one suggested by @tagwint

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on your shell, there usually has to be a `.<shellnamehere>rc` file where you can store these variables that you want persisting across logout and reboot events. `.bashrc` is where you do it if your shell choice is `bash`

**EDIT**:
in the terminal, run command

```
env | grep SHELL
```

if you see `SHELL=bash` then, run this command:

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.71-2.b15.el7_2.x86_64"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

this last command have some assumptions. If your SHELL doesn't come up as `bash` come back here and report what you get. After a logout and login back if you don't see your variable already set, again come back and report what error messages you see, if any.

Comment: Your solution is a perfect one. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

If it is about setting JAVA_HOME system-wide, `/etc/profile.d/` would be a good choice.

```
echo export JAVA_HOME="put path to java home here">/etc/profile.d/javaenv.sh
chmod 0755 /etc/profile.d/javaenv.sh
```

on your next logon you'll have it

Comment: This one is useful so services will have it available as well :)